# Strong password for SQL Server doesn't follow the documentation

Tags: sql-server-express, sa

I'm installing a new instance of SQL Server Express with mixed mode for access. The password I'm setting is `Abcd1234()`. According to [the docs for strong password guidelines](https://documentation.help/s10ch_setup/834b26bc-49de-4033-88d5-6aa7b1609720.htm), it's supposed to be valid if it consists of more than 8 of the following:

- uppercase letters,
- lowercase letters,
- numbers, and
- non-alphanumeric characters.

My entry satisfies all of the above. Yet, I can't proceed as the validation claims violated rules for strong passwords.

> The specified sa password does not meet strong password requirements. For more information about strong password requirements, see "Database Engine Configuration - Account Provisioning" in Setup Help or in SQL Server 2019 Books Online.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem.

I didn't find any information titled "Database Engine Configuration - Account Provisioning" in the official Microsoft SQL Server documentation, as mentioned in the error message. So I still don't know what SQL Server's strong password rules are.

But from what I've gathered, when one is connected to a domain, the password you enter must meet the domain's strong password rules.  In my case, it requires a password of at least 14 characters in addition to containing numbers, letters, and symbols. When I entered a password that met those requirements, it was finally accepted.

Obviously, your domain may have different password rules.